# ELMAH not displaying Original ASP.NET error page in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

http://www.matheda.com/Blog/Details/3/Exception-Logging-with-ELMAH

Using the above url as a reference, I can see ELMAH should display the Original ASP.NET error page when the error originates from the View.

I have created the following view to generate an error, but the only exception views are Raw/Source data in XML or in JSON.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewError";
}

<h2>View Error</h2>

@{
  throw new NullReferenceException();
}
```

Is it possible to view the Original ASP.NET error page in MVC3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC3 now has a different process for handling errors that bypasses the HttpApplication's error handling, and I am not sure that ELMAH can recreate the yellow screen of death at that point.

[CodeSmith Insight](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/insight/elmah) has very similar functionality to ELMAH, and we had to create a new MVC3 specific HttpModule to continue getting all of our exception details. Here is a [blog post about our implementation](http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/02/15/working-with-mvc3-s-globalfilters-and-handleerrorattribute.aspx), hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I Recall Correctly, [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) will call [Server.GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524846%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which means if any error happened after the error you're expecting, you might get an ELMAH report that is different than your expectations.

I know this happened to me when my 404 page wasn't really there... I got spammed by page-not-found errors when there was a different error altogether.